# How to compute the matrix of minors of this matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose am given a matrix in the form of A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d& e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}

I am trying to compute the matrix of minors for that object in a computer program but I am not sure if the expressions I have used are correct. The minors have been labeled from m1 to m9. the expressions are listed below.

***m1=ei-hf***

***m2=di-gf***

***m3=dh-ge***

***m4=bi-hc***

***m5=ai-gc***

***m6=ah-bg***

***m7=bf-ec***

***m8=af-dc***

***m9=ae-db***

Can I present the matrix of minors computed above like below

M=\begin{bmatrix}m1 & m1 & m3 \\ m4& m5 & m6 \\ m7 & m8 & m9\end{bmatrix}

Just needed some confirmation or cross-checking by an expert before I complete the statements in my program, Thank You.

Comment: Yes, those are the minors. [I assume you had a typo and the $m_1$ in row 1 col 2 should be $m_2.$] Also the minors are usually denoted using double subscripts corresponding to which original matrix entry had its row and column omitted to get the minor.

Comment: @coffeemath, okay thanks for confirming that for me, this project is big and massive, Thank you so much.

Comment: @coffeemath, for the matrix of co-factors, I just apply a negation on alternate elements of the matrix of minors?

Comment: Kinyua... I don't follow your last comment. You already have the matrix of cofactors, I don't see what you mean by doing anything like "apply a negation on altermate elements...". There's nothing else needed to do to get the cofactor matrix.

Comment: But that is the matrix of minors, the one I posted, I need the co-factor matrix from that.

Comment: Oh I see. Cofactors, as distinct from minors, have a factor $(-1)^{i+j}$ multiplied, and also I think one takes the transpose. But look these terms up, maybe via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To find the minor of a matrix, we take the determinant of each smaller matrix, obtained by deleting the corresponding rows and columns of each element in the matrix. Since in the large matrices, there are many rows and columns with multiple elements, therefore we can make many minors of those matrices. We label these minors according to the row and column they belong to. Each element in the square matrix has its minor.
$$
M_{11}=
\begin{bmatrix}
e & f\\
h & i
\end{bmatrix}
=(ei-fh),
$$
$$
M_{12}=
\begin{bmatrix}
d & f\\
g & i
\end{bmatrix}
=(di-fg),
$$
$$
M_{13}=
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e\\
g & h
\end{bmatrix}
=(dh-eg),
$$
$$
M_{21}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b & c\\
h & i
\end{bmatrix}
=(bi-ch),
$$
$$
M_{22}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
g & i
\end{bmatrix}
=(ai-cg),
$$
$$
M_{23}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
g & h
\end{bmatrix}
=(ah-bg),
$$
$$
M_{31}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b & c\\
e & f
\end{bmatrix}
=(bf-ce),
$$
$$
M_{32}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
d & f
\end{bmatrix}
=(af-cd),
$$
$$
M_{33}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
d & e
\end{bmatrix}
=(ae-bd),
$$
Therefore,
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{11} & M_{11}\\
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23}\\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e & f\\
h & i
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
d & f\\
g & i
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e\\
g & h
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
b & c\\
h & i
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
g & i
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
g & h
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
b & c\\
e & f
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
d & f
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
d & e
\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The cofactor of the element is denoted as $C_{ij}$. If the minor of the element is $M_{ij}$, therefore, the cofactor of element would be $C_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}$.
$$
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
(-1)^{1+1}M_{11} & (-1)^{1+2}M_{12} & (-1)^{1+3}M_{13} \\ 
(-1)^{2+1}M_{21} & (-1)^{2+2}M_{22} & (-1)^{2+3}M_{23} \\ 
(-1)^{3+1}M_{31} & (-1)^{3+2}M_{32} & (-1)^{3+3}M_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Hey how do I get the matrix of co-factors from that?

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU, I have added the matrix of cofactors.

Comment: Suppose I got the matrix of minors as `MM=[1 2 3   4 5 6  789]`, what would the co-factor matrix be?

Comment: $C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & 3\\-4 & 5 & -6\\7 & -8 & 9\end{pmatrix}$